# How to enforce TLS on Gmail (Gsuite Basic)

Tags: ssl, gmail, google-workspace

I want to strictly enforce TLS on all inbound/outbound emails from gmail (gsuite basic) for a particular organization/domain. I did read this article:

https://support.google.com/a/answer/2520500?hl=en

It asks to create an address list to setup inbound/outbound rule to enforce TLS. However I want to have TLS enforced irrespective of address and want to enable following behavior:

Outgoing mail:  Mail won't be delivered and will bounce. You'll get a non-delivery report (NDR). Only one send attempt is made (no tries again).

Incoming mail:  Mail is rejected without any notification to you, although the sender will receive an NDR.

Any suggestions on how this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

You can’t do that, in fact based in this article at point 6.:
https://support.google.com/a/answer/2520500?hl=en

“You must create a domain or address list to enforce TLS compliance for any inbound or outbound messages”

Gmail by default will use TLS, however, if the destination domain can’t establish TLS connection, Gmail will do an insecure connection. However, nowadays all domains are all by default establishing TLS connection and transmitting data over it. It’s rare you will find a domain that doesn’t support TLS connection.

Therefore, first of all,  you should know which domains you usually contact that doesn't support TLS connection, and listed in the TLS compliance rules.
The idea of this policy is not making a long list of domains but only a few that customers already know that they don’t support TLS connection hence list them on the TLS.

There is a feature for a higher message encryption but is available for G Suite Enterprise edition: https://support.google.com/a/answer/6374496?hl=en

In fact what it may be a workaround is to Send and receive your email first to an external server that allows you to achieve this.

If this is the case you should Set up:

> Set up an inbound mail gateway: https://support.google.com/a/answer/60730?hl=en

> Set up an outbound mail gateway: https://support.google.com/a/answer/178333?hl=en

An consider a third party tool as : https://zix.com/products/email-encryption